# how to detect if another java thread is suspended or frozen?

Tags: java, multithreading, 3d, mouse

I searched and found ways to determine if another thread is suspended by adding a boolean to it. But, I do not want (prefer not) to modify that other thread's code. And, I need to detect if it is frozen by any reason (even a bug, so in this case that other thread may also be unresponsive).

I see how eclipse does it and shows the application's thread is not responding, I wonder how they coded that.

Motivation: I need this to release the mouse (ungrab it) from a 3D lwjgl application, and this must be independent of any IDE, the application itself must do it. I am trying to monitor the main application thread.

Answer (score 3):

While not necessarily the best idea, you can use [`Thread#getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()) to view the current state of the thread.

However, this will depend on the context of the thread. If it is frozen because it cannot break out of a loop, then this method cannot work. Additionally, if it is simply waiting on a lock or on a bounded collection, it will be a false call.

The thread should in these 3 states: [`BLOCKED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED), [`WAITING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING), or [`TIMED_WAITING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING).

Comment: oh, I mean I need to know another thread state; not the current; now I understand the -1 I got sry.. editing..

Comment: I think I can, have to check, but that means I could simply check its state like you pointed?

Comment: Yes, be forewarned that you still can have a false alarm if the thread is in those states waiting on a lock or a bounded collection.

Comment: on linux at least, we can see the threads activity (cpu usage) on command line, if I could find the pid of the thread and check if it has cpu usage thru exec() it could work too I guess

Comment: but... I just thought also, if that thread regularly modifies some accessible variable or generate some kind of output, monitoring any of these could also be a great guess to determine when to ungrab the mouse

Answer (score 0):

in a powershell or command prompt you could use JPS to list all java threads that are currently running. then use jstack "pid" .. this will list all threads running under this thread. their state will also be written next to them.